# MVC design issue

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, grid, datacontext

I'm having an application using MVC. It has a canvas and property grid. When an item is selected in the canvas. The property grid should display its details.

So I made an event listener and when item is selected in the canvas it raises an event to the controller which pass the selected item to the property grid to display the details.

Model :

Item object containing name, description

Controller :

```
protected Controller(object model, FrameworkElement view)
{
    this._model = model;
    this._view = view;
}

public virtual void Initialize()
{
    View.DataContext = Model;
}
```

View :

```
<TextBlock>Status</TextBlock>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="?????"/>
```

Where view is the property grid and model is the selected item.

The problem is in the property grid there is a dropdown list containing lookup values how can I get the dropdown values given that the datacontext of the property grid has already been set to the selected item which doesn't contain reference to these lookup items.

I know that it's easy to use custom code to do that. But I don't want to violate the MVC aproach.

Comment: Much more information is needed to give a sensible answer(which is why imho no one has replied till now :))
I would do this:
- Create a data interface, say, IListProvider which could have a method called "ProvideList" accepting a TStringBuilder as parameter
- Create a singleton implementation class for the interface
- Create an interface property for the context and use that to select the "right" provider.

Still, I think you need to outline your code :)

Comment: @Andrea: It has only been 7 minutes though...

Comment: @Andrea: I thought of that but the problem is from MVC perspective the user interface is seperate from the data. It must be done through a controller class. What I needed is someway of assigning multiple model sources to one view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to a source rather than DataContext, sources are provided by [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx), [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) & [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx), so you can name the View for example and use `ElementName` to get it as source then the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) could be `DataContext.LookupValues` or whatever your property in the model (- the DataContext of the View is your model -) is called.

---

e.g.

```xml
<Window ...
    Name="Window">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=DataContext.Occupations}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Occupation}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <!-- ... --->
```

---

**Edit:** Your problem seems to be that you do not pass the information you need, consider a design which still grants you access to more than just the SelectedItem of some list, e.g.

```xml
<Window ...
        Name="Window">
    <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=DataContext.Occupations}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Occupation}" />
    </ContentControl>

    <!-- ... --->
```

The `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` may be the SelectedItem of the ListBox but the ComboBox inside can still reference the DataContext of the Window which should provide the necessary information.

This is similar to my first example in that the DataContext inside the DataTemplate is always an item of the collection but you can access external DataContexts using sources in your bindings.

Comment: Can you give an example,please?

Comment: Added an example, note the `Window.Name` and the `ItemsSource`-binding of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: That is not something which one *"defines"*, the DataContext of the Window is the model, an instance of whatever model class you have, so `Occupations` has to be a property declared in the model-class.

Comment: But the model here is the selected item which doesn't have any reference to the lookup data

Comment: Oh right, you are not supposed to pass less inforation to a control than it actually needs. There is no way to retrieve the information from the SelectedItem alone. In fact you normally are not supposed to pass around models like that anyway but that is beside this question. As has been noted Andrea Raimondi your question lacks a lot of context, that would be neded to be any more concrete. (Also please don't prematurely accept answers if you are not yet sure that it works)

Comment: I hope my edits make the approach clear, you can just access about any model you want.